# What happens to an SSIS package when I alter a table that is used as a destination?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

My apologizes if this question doesn't correspond to this site. 
I have this question because in a SQL Server is deployed a SSIS Package (is a very old package) and I don't have the dtsx file.

Now I need to add some columns to a table, but this table is used as a destination on this package. So my question is, if I alter the table, will the package continue to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the table nothing will happen to the SSIS package. If you only add columns it will probably still work, but if you change data types on columns already used in the destination you might break things. If you were talking about the source that could be a whole different matter depending on how your columns are mapped but again if you only add columns and the mappings are done on a name basis chances are it will just work.

> In a SQL Server is deployed a SSIS Package (is a very old package) and I don't have the dtsx file.

What you should do is create a new SSIS project and add an "existing file". That way you'll have the source again.

See [Add Copy of Existing Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/add-copy-of-existing-package):

> Use the Add Copy of Existing Package dialog box to add a copy of a
>   package stored in SQL Server, the file system, or the SSIS Package
>   Store to an Integration Services project.

The exact procedure changes a bit from version to version but I think you should be able to figure it out.

In general I would advise you to create a new source file for the package and test it in a test environment as there is no guarantee it will continue to work even though it probably will if you're only adding columns and don't change any of the columns used in the destination

Comment: If there's a `SELECT *` in there it could break something, too.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik sure but the OP was talking about a destination. I'll update a bit more though

Comment: The ssis package after making changes on columns stop doing the updates. It needs to be deployed again with the modifications.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't changing the destination table *name* or the name or properties of any existing columns, then the package may continue to run without any changes.

If you need to actually include these new columns in your import, though, then you will probably need to update the package.

If you don't have the dtsx file, then I assume the package is published in an SSISDB?

Here are some articles that discuss editing/exporting a published package for different SQL/SSIS versions:

- [How to export a package from SSISDB?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e4cbdafd-28b4-486d-b0d2-3bc74f4fc3ac/how-to-export-a-package-from-ssisdb?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Editing Published SSIS Package in SQL Server 2012](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/editing-published-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012.html).